GCC cross-compile - undefined reference errors
Update 2: So the undefined reference to __end is this:
opt/i386-pc-coff/lib/ndp//libc.a(brk.o):(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `__end'

But when I do objdump of that libc.a file, I see it defined.
brk.o:     file format coff-i386
<...snip...>
SYMBOL TABLE:
[  0](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 0) 0x00000000 .text
[  1](sec  2)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 0) 0x00000048 .data
[  2](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 0) 0x0000004c .bss
[  3](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 sbrk
[  4](sec  0)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 __end
[  5](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000002a brk
[  6](sec  0)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 .cerror

So I don't really get what the error really means.
Update 1: It appears that gcc 3.1 and 3.2 have a bug in gcc/libgcc2.c where the macro EH_FRAME_SECTION_NAME triggers some #ifdef statements that shouldn't be triggered for coff and hms targets, according to this old email thread.  I commented some bits out and now the undefined references to __EH_FRAME_BEGIN__ are gone.  The undefined reference to __end still exists, but I am researching if an .ld linker script can't fix things.
Original Message: I am attempting to use my gcc cross-compiler for the first time with a simple Hello World program and I have encountered a number of road blocks.  I am using gcc 3.2.3 with a i386-freebsd host, i386-pc-coff target, and binutils 2.19.1a.  Everything was built with a prefix of "~/opt".  I've placed the contents of /usr/include, /usr/lib, and /lib from my target machine into "~/opt/i386-pc-coff".
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello World!");
}

When I attempt to use the standard startup files and libraries when linking, I receive the following error:
[user@vm-fbsd ~]$ i386-pc-coff-gcc -v -D__COHERENT__ helloworld.c
Reading specs from /home/user/opt/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-coff/3.2.3/specs
Configured with: ../gcc-3.2.3/configure --target=i386-pc-coff --prefix=/home/user/opt --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: single
gcc version 3.2.3
 /home/user/opt/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-coff/3.2.3/cc1 -lang-c -v -D__GNUC__=3 -D__GNUC_MINOR__=2 -D__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__=3 -D__GXX_ABI_VERSION=102 -D__NO_INLINE__ -D__STDC_HOSTED__=1 -Acpu=i386 -Amachine=i386 -Di386 -D__i386 -D__i386__ -D__tune_i386__ -D__COHERENT__ helloworld.c -quiet -dumpbase helloworld.c -version -o /var/tmp//ccMJ21ag.s
GNU CPP version 3.2.3 (cpplib) (80386, BSD syntax)
GNU C version 3.2.3 (i386-pc-coff)
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/user/opt/i386-pc-coff/sys-include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/user/opt/include
 /home/user/opt/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-coff/3.2.3/include
 /home/user/opt/i386-pc-coff/include
End of search list.
 /home/user/opt/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-coff/3.2.3/../../../../i386-pc-coff/bin/as --traditional-format -o /var/tmp//ccA3Y8bB.o /var/tmp//ccMJ21ag.s
 /home/user/opt/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-coff/3.2.3/collect2 /home/user/opt/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-coff/3.2.3/../../../../i386-pc-coff/lib/crt0.o -L/home/user/opt/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-coff/3.2.3 -L/home/user/opt/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-coff/3.2.3/../../../../i386-pc-coff/lib /var/tmp//ccA3Y8bB.o -lgcc -lc -lgcc
/home/user/opt/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-coff/3.2.3/libgcc.a(__main.o): In function `__do_global_dtors':
libgcc2.c:1901: undefined reference to `__EH_FRAME_BEGIN__'
/home/user/opt/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-coff/3.2.3/libgcc.a(__main.o): In function `__do_global_ctors':
libgcc2.c:1917: undefined reference to `__EH_FRAME_BEGIN__'
/home/user/opt/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-coff/3.2.3/../../../../i386-pc-coff/lib/libc.a(brk.o):(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `__end'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

My startup file:
[user@vm-fbsd ~/opt/i386-pc-coff/lib]$ i386-pc-coff-objdump -x crt0.o

crt0.o:     file format coff-i386
crt0.o
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000035:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_LINENO, HAS_SYMS, HAS_LOCALS
start address 0x00000000

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         0000002c  00000000  00000000  0000008c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  0000002c  0000002c  00000000  2**2
                  ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000004  0000002c  0000002c  00000000  2**2
                  ALLOC
SYMBOL TABLE:
[  0](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 0) 0x00000000 .text
[  1](sec  2)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 0) 0x0000002c .data
[  2](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 0) 0x0000002c .bss
[  3](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000002c environ
[  4](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 _start
[  5](sec  0)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 exit
[  6](sec  0)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 main
[  7](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000001e _exit


RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE
00000009 dir32             .bss+0xffffffd4
00000011 DISP32            main
0000001a DISP32            exit

I am not using --sysroot because it isn't included in gcc 3.  I'm not using gcc 4 or later because both *-coff and *-sysv targets were deprecated.  Thoughts?

What platform will the code run on? As in, what hardware/OS does i386-pc-coff correspond to?

Coherent 4.2 for i386.
